# Power Automate - Insert/ Updates rows in On-prem SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

My goal is to copy data from one SQL table to another SQL Table.

I'm trying to create a conditional Insert/Update statement in Power Automate based on Row ID. I have two tables right now with the same columns.

1. Source SQL Table
2. Destination SQL Table

I would like to update rows if Row ID already exists or create new if already not exists.

I tried Execute SQL query  but this is not supported.(Known issues)

I tried "Transform data using Power Query to fetch rows from Source and Destination" and then had if condition to compare "Source.ProjectName = Dest.ProjectName" then its going into two Apply each conditions but still not creating items..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like searching for an answer to your specific problem and finding exactly one other person with the same issue, but no resolution.

Fortunately, I've managed to work out a decent solution for an SQL Upsert with an On-Premises SQL Connector in Power Automate.

Here's the general overview, I'll go through step-by-step after:

[image: Overview Screenshot]

First step is to retrieve the single row by ID using Get row (V2).

[image: Get Row]

The next step is to parse the JSON of the body of the previous call.

[image: Parse JSON]

Here is the Schema that I used:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "status": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "error": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "message": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "source": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Now the key bit, hit Configure Run After for the Parse JSON action and have it run on both Success and Failure of the previous action.

[image: Run after]

Then we add a conditional that checks the status code of the Get Row action (as output by the Parse JSON action). If it failed with a 404 Status, we do an Insert. Otherwise, do an Update.

Hopefully this helps anyone else trying to work around the limitations of the On-Premises connector.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a limitation that I ran into with both MySQL Get Row and Update Row because of my index column format -- my key is a triplet, like (9999,876,0).

Both Get Row and Update Row think that 3 keys are being passed because the contents have a comma in them.

MS support confirmed that this is a limitation, no special characters can be in the index contents, and no workaround.

I will have to figure out another tool set for my use case on this table...